# How to interpret data output from Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weka

I have attached auto_price.arff [here](http://pastebin.com/DUMmc1TH)

Requirement:

- Partition the dataset suitable
- Build a (multilayer feed forward)
  neural network model to predict the price of a car.
- Submit a report
  documenting your findings, together with a disk containing your work
  (e.g. Weka, report, etc).

Limit your analysis to models with one hidden layer and two hidden layers only.
Comment on your findings and the performance of the models.

I tried but I got to answer this, I really don't have any idea how to predict value or How to interpret data output from Weka?

```
=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.8937
Mean absolute error                   1755.407 
Root mean squared error               2633.987 
Relative absolute error                 38.0947 %
Root relative squared error             44.646  %
Total Number of Instances              159
```

Comment: Do not expect us to do your **homework**.

Comment: I dont have any idea to judgement of predict price?

Comment: You have copy-pasted your homework, it seems. Unbelievable!

Answer (score 0):

The output is the result of automatic *evaluation* via cross-validation.

Of course it is not a prediction, because it has not been applied to new data yet. But you were not asked to execute a prediction anyway.